# Parcel.js javascript problem when adding attributes to img element

Tags: javascript, image, sass, parceljs

**Parcel.js** can't figure out what is the path when it reads **.js** file.

code:

```
 image.setAttribute("src", `../images/icon-${el}.svg`)
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import rockImage from "../images/icon-rock.svg"
import paperImage from "../images/icon-paper.svg"
import scissorsImage from "../images/icon-scissors.svg"

let img = document.createElement("img")
img.src = rockImage
```

Firstly import the images with "Import", and then append it to the newly created "img" element.